# PostgreSQL : is it possible to add in child table first using alter table to remove F.K and then adding data in parent table?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, relational-database

I've 2 tables Address(parent) and Store(child) and both the tables are empty.

Is it possible to insert data in the store table(child) with a foreign key value in this and this foreign key value gets added in Address(parent) automatically using postgreSQL query?

```
Address(Parent)

id (P.K)
city
street 
house


Store(Child)

id 
phone
name
Address_id (F.K)
```

Step 1: first add data in the **store** table containing **F.K** of the **Parent** table considering both of them are empty. I've tried adding by disabling F.K but as I re-assign F.k It is giving me

"ERROR: insert or update on table "store" violates foreign key constraint "store_address_fkey"
Detail: Key (address)=(1) is not present in table "address".
"

Step 2: After **Step1 problem resolves** I want to add corresponding **F.K(store) to P.K(address)** in **Parent** table.

Any method available to do this type of query generation.

```
Error:

ERROR: Migration of schema "public" to version "4 - Insert" failed! Changes successfully rolled back.
ERROR: Migration V4__Insert.sql failed
-------------------------------
SQL State  : 23503
Error Code : 0
Message    : ERROR: insert or update on table "store" violates foreign key constraint "store_address_fkey"
  Detail: Key (address)=(1) is not present in table "address".
Location   : sql/V4__Insert.sql (/home/naveen.p@ah.zymrinc.com/flyway-9.2.2/sql/V4__Insert.sql)
Line       : 1
Statement  : INSERT INTO store(ID, PHONE, NAME, ADDRESS) VALUES(1, '88002001453', 'MskSouvenir', 1)

Caused by: Migration V4__Insert.sql failed
-------------------------------
SQL State  : 23503
Error Code : 0
Message    : ERROR: insert or update on table "store" violates foreign key constraint "store_address_fkey"
  Detail: Key (address)=(1) is not present in table "address".
Location   : sql/V4__Insert.sql (/home/naveen.p@ah.zymrinc.com/flyway-9.2.2/sql/V4__Insert.sql)
Line       : 1
Statement  : INSERT INTO store(ID, PHONE, NAME, ADDRESS) VALUES(1, '88002001453', 'MskSouvenir', 1)

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: insert or update on table "store" violates foreign key constraint "store_address_fkey"
  Detail: Key (address)=(1) is not present in table "address".
```

Comment: Look into : https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29147/postgresql-insert-update-violates-foreign-key-constraints

Comment: It didn't work.                                                                                                                          

update: I've tried by disabling F.K in Child table added data but as soon as I tried to given F.K using alter it is again showing that error.

Question: Can we set a variable temp to store F.K. value and come up with the solution?

Comment: What is stopping you adding the data to the parent table before you add it to the child table? You need to decide whether you want use FKs or not - if you do want to use them then there is no "solution", you just use FKs as they are designed to be used

Comment: I've to do this as a challenge. I've tried to solve this but couldn't... Now I'm looking to use a separate variable for F.K... Please provide some suggestions this task can be done in multiple queries too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to insert data into a child table if the corresponding parent record does not exist and the FK is active. The point of defining FKs is precisely to prevent this happening